# VB.NET SSL Certificate Authentication Exception

Tags: vb.net, certificate, certificate-authority

I am new to VB.Net coding && I am having some problems with my HTTTP(s) debugger application. [using a self-signed certificate]
Every other thing works fine but when authentication occurs between my browser and my application an exception is thrown:

> A call to SSPI failed see inner exception

The inner exception says:

> the certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

How can I evade this exception?

I have tried installing the certificate to my trusted authority certificate list but this problem still occurs, or do I have to disable the certificate check in .NET if yes then how can I do that?